# How can I use D3 to create a stacked area chart of this data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Pre-emptive apology and caveat**

I'm super-sorry for asking a question that falls squarely in the category of "show me the code" but I'm just at a loss. Also, the answer to "what have you tried" will be, "I don't have any idea what to do."

**Question**

Given the following data, how would I convert the following data set to a stacked area chart?

I'd acquire the data by means of:

```
d3.json('/link/to/data', function(data) {
    ... //how do I convert the data to layers here?
    });
    //set up my axes and such here
);
```

The data itself is pivoted and summarized already. The first column would be the layer key (verb tense) and the subsequent numbers are counts of the occurrences of verbs of that tense per verse (in Homer's *Odyssey*) for a range of verses.

How would I convert each tense to a layer? Do I actually need to summarize or is there a better way to go about this?

Again, I'm sorry for the basic nature of this question.

Here's what the summarized data coming from the database would look like

```
{'tense': 'Present', '1.1':1, '1.2':3, '1.3':3, '1.4':0, '1.5':1}
```

Comment: Did you look at their examples? http://bl.ocks.org/3886208

Comment: I did. Do stacked area and stacked bar work the same?

Comment: Ugh - I'm sorry - I read it as stacked bar - here's a stacked area chart example: http://bl.ocks.org/3885211